# NumericUpDown equivalent in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt

This one should be easy, but I didn't find it in Google:

Is there an equivalent control to .Net's `System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown` in Java?

The functionality required is to select a valid decimal or integer number.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a [JSpinner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) control available in Swing.

Answer (score 3):

If you're in Swing land, use a [JSpinner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html) - it works in numbers by default but can be customised to work with months, dates, or pretty much anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the link and the extra info.  Vlad's answer appeared first, but you get my upvote.  (:

Comment: -1 for duplicate answer. No need to clutter the forum. YOu can delete your answer when you notice the same suggestion has been given.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html

Comment: Thanks!  @Vlad's answer appeared first, but you get my upvote. (:

Comment: -1 for duplicate answer. No need to clutter the forum. YOu can delete your answer when you notice the same suggestion has been given.

Comment: @camickr: too bad you weren't here to clean this up over 10 years ago.  Jeez.